# How to get the perform a difference in each sublist of a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list that would be the difference between the last and the first element of each sublist of a list. Sublists are sublists of N elements, so I will have `len(list)/K+1` elements in my final list.

---

Here is a little example:

I have a list : `[0, 10, 20, 5, 10, 30, 20, 35]`. I chose to have a maximum of 3 elements per sublist. I will have the following sublists `[0, 10, 20], [5, 10, 30], [20, 35]`.

Now I apply the difference in each sublist and I get the values `20, 25, 15` (because `20-0`, `30-5` and `35-20`).

I want the result to be in a list, so to have `[20, 25, 15]` as a final result.

Comment: `(list[0]-list[-1])` ?

Comment: There are more than one group of those numbers in the list. I suppose I need to split the list then do what you said, @txemsukr.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389097/6296561)

Answer (score 3):

As requested in the original version of the question, and according to the edits made by the OP, we create a list of increasing sequences, then calculate the differences between the max and min of each of them:

```
def spans(data):
    sequences = [[data[0]]]

    for val in data[1:]:
        if val >= sequences[-1][-1]:
            sequences[-1].append(val)
        else:
            sequences.append([val])

    return [s[-1] -s[0] for s in sequences]
```

Sample run with the OP's data:

```
data = [0, 10, 20, 5, 10, 30, 20, 35]
print(spans(data))
# [20, 25, 15]
```

Another one:

```
print(spans([2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 4, 5, -2, -1, 5, 4]))
# [7, 1, 7, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that should help you.

Care if you have only one element in the last sublist, I don't know how you want to deal with this case. I considered that the element is the result of this sublist, but maybe you want to ignore the last sublist or to have 0 as a result.

Explanations are the comments in the script:

```
# Initial list
l = [0, 10, 20, 5, 10, 30, 20, 35]

# Number of elements to consider in each sublist.
STEP = 3

# Get the size of the list
length = len(l)

# The result list, empty at the beginning, that will be populated by the differences
result_list = []

# Iterate through sublists of exactly STEP elements
i = 0
while (i+STEP-1)<length:
    result_list.append(l[i+STEP-1]-l[i])
    i += STEP

# Special case for the possible little last sublist
# No difference done and element is kept if there is only one element
if i==length-1:
    result_list.append(l[-1])
# Else, do the difference in the last sublist
elif i<length-1:
    result_list.append(l[-1]-l[i])
```

---

Here is the script that takes the `max-min` of each sublist, as OP asked primarily:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = 3

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

# Create the sublists
grouped_l = list(chunks(l,n))

# Do the max-min on each sublists
res = []
for i in grouped_l:
    res.append(max(i)-min(i))
```

Comment: The algorithm you are using here, though it matches the edits you made to the question, contradicts the last edit by the OP himself, that clearly states 'So the initial list needs to be split into the groups of incrementing numbers'

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think that this is not what OP wants and that his sentence is not correct because else you can't have the same result than the one he has in his example (or I missed something). What OP calls incrementation seems to be, in fact, sublists.

Comment: The OP's last edit is clear and coherent with his example: `[0, 10, 20, 5, 10, 30, 20, 35]` contains the increasing sequences `[0, 10, 20]` , `[5, 10, 30]` and `[20, 35]`, and the differences between the max and min of each are 20, 25 and 15. As a side note, your edit should have been rejected as it deviates from the original intent of the question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I've updated to have both version : one for what OP asked first, and one for the actual version of the question

Comment: It is just the same, written differently. The point is: the sub-sequences are not fixed length (3), they are the increasing subsequences. In `[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 4, 5, -2, -1, 5, 4]`, they would be `[2, 4, 6, 8, 9], [4, 5], [-2, -1, 5], [4]`

Comment: I added an answer showing what was meant, with test cases.

Comment: Oh OK, I now see what the OP called incrementation